# Insertion in BST ,Iterative Solution in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, iteration, binary-search-tree

I have an online programming assignment for my class and I've been trying to figure out a solution for the task that says:

> You have to create a function that inserts a new (int ) data to a BST iteratively. The first parameter it gets is the pointer to the root of the BST, then the (int ) data you have to insert.
> The parts of the tree look like this:

```
 typedef struct _node 
{
    int data;
    struct _node* left;
    struct _node* right;
} node;
```

> In the tree you always find the lower values on the left, the greater values on the right. None of the values are duplicated,
> **So the function should not insert the value that is already the part of the BST**

```
//My function that I've been working on looks like this: 

node* newNode(int key)
{
    node* uj = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
    if (uj != NULL)
    {
        uj->data = key;
        uj->left = uj->right = NULL;
    }
    return uj;
}
void insert(node* root, int key)
{
    node* curr = root;
    node* parent = NULL;
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = newNode(key);
        return;
    }
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        parent = curr;
        if (key == curr->data)
            return;
        if (key < curr->data)
            curr = curr->left;
        if (key > curr->data)
            curr = curr->right;
    }
    if (key < parent->data)
        parent->left = newNode(key);
    else
        parent->right = newNode(key);
}
```

I think this should be working just fine, since the class actually is "basics of programming 1" at an Electrical engineering faculty.

I have seen similar questions, with good answers, **but** since this line exists in the description of the task

- **So the function should not insert the value that is already the part of the BST**

I were not able to complete my assignment, because at the online complier, or tester says this :[The picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/944zy.png)
The worst part is that I am running low on tries, and if I fail I will not be able to pass this class..

Thank you in order for your time if you decite to help me solve this task!

Comment: Are you sure a null pointer can be passed in? Because, `root = newNode(key);` really makes no sense here, as it would only be modifying the local `root` variable and the newly allocated node would be beyond the reach of the calling code?

Comment: That is to say, I don't know the constraints of the "tester", but as-is, if you expect the insert function to also be able to modify the root of the tree, you will have to either make it return the root node, changing the signature to `node *insert(node *root, int key)` or pass the address of the root to the insert function changing the signature to `void insert(node **root, int key);`

Comment: *"I think this should be working just fine"* - it's not. `root = newNode(key);` means *nothing* to the caller of this function (which is not shown here anyway). All that line does is change the value of `root` *within the function*, where it is an automatic variable. it does not change the variable (if any) passed by the *caller* of `insert`. If the specification is exactly as described `void insert(node *root, int key)`, what they're asking for is impossible *unless* the callers `root` is pre-populated before ever calling your function. And we have no way of knowing that either.